# createElement within for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an element 50 times within a for loop. My code is below:

```
function pGenerate() {
  for (i, i <= 50; i++;) {
    var newP = document.createElement("p");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("sample paragraph");
    newP.appendChild(pText);

    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content");
    document.body.insertBefore(newP, contentSection);
  }
}
```

The expected result is that it generates 50 `<p>` tags with "sample content inside of them. The actual result is well...nothing. https://jsfiddle.net/2L8reked/1/

My thought process behind the code I wrote this code is as follows: I basically have a loop set to cycle 50 times. for each cycle, I want to create a `p` tag, along with create a text node with the content "sample paragraph." In the next step, I grab the `div` by it's id, `#content`, and I then attempt to populate the area using `insertBefore`.

My error here seems to be how I use `insertBefore`. Looking this up on MDN, it's definition is "inserts the specified node before the reference node as a child of the current node." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

With that definition in mind - I'm using this with the understanding as of now that I'm inserting (or attempting to) the `p` tags as a child of `#content`. Should I be using a different method? Am I misunderstanding how this works?

I also tried an `innerHTML` approach, seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/0e1ej9sk/1/

1. which method is best suited for what I'm trying to do?
2. In the first example what is the flaw behind my logic of the use of `insertBefore`?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but you should build up your entire html first and then add to the DOM in a single operation.  It's much better for performance.

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log#t=201706211437487409473) You've got an error. If you fix your syntax errors, it works just fine.

Comment: In both you have a typo in your loop. It should be : `for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) { ... }`.

Comment: ... `undefined <= 50 -> false`, the loop is never entered.

Comment: You should really consider re-reading about `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 syntax errors.

Change `i,` in for loop to `1=1;` then remove the last `;` where `i++;` to `i++`

```js
function pGenerate() {
  for (i=1; i <= 50; i++) {
    var newP = document.createElement("p");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("sample paragraph");
    newP.appendChild(pText);
    
    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content");
    document.body.insertBefore(newP, contentSection);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  pGenerate();
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `i` at `1`, and properly separate all parts of the `for` statement with semi-colons, like this:

```js
function pGenerate() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    var newP = document.createElement("p");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("sample paragraph (i=" + i + ")");
    newP.appendChild(pText);

    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content");
    document.body.insertBefore(newP, contentSection);
  }
}

pGenerate();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
function pGenerate() {
  for (i=1; i <= 50; i++) {
    var newP = document.createElement("p");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("sample paragraph");
    newP.appendChild(pText);
    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content");
    document.body.insertBefore(newP, contentSection);
  }
}

document.ready(pGenerate);
```